# How to get CoreAnnotations.CoNLLDepAnnotation and CoreAnnotations.GovernorAnnotation as annotators through StanfordCorenlp pipeline?

Tags: stanford-nlp

There are standard names for annotations (like tokenize, ssplit, pos) but i am not sure what name should be specified for the CoNLLDepAnnotations and GovernorAnnotations and also what other annotations does these depend on.

Answer (score 0):

Dependency Parse require the annotator (parse). All dependency that you mentioned are performed under this annotator. The code below will print the semantic graph of the sentence in a List format.

```
for (CoreMap sentenceAnnotation:art.sentences){
    SemanticGraph deps = sentenceAnnotation.get(SemanticGraphCoreAnnotations.CollapsedDependenciesAnnotation.class);
    System.out.println(deps.toList());
}
```

For example the output of the sentence: `Apple even went as far to make an electric guitar version .` will be:

```
root(ROOT-0, went-3)
nsubj(went-3, Apple-1)
advmod(went-3, even-2)
advmod(far-5, as-4)
advmod(went-3, far-5)
mark(make-7, to-6)
xcomp(went-3, make-7)
det(version-11, an-8)
amod(version-11, electric-9)
compound(version-11, guitar-10)
dobj(make-7, version-11)
punct(went-3, .-12)
```

where for the first token `Apple` the relation is nsubj and the governor is the third token `went`.

Comment: Can you help me in getting the actual dependent and governor annotations from the document for individual tokens after annotating from the following code: 
Properties props = new Properties(); props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner,parse"); StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props); Annotation document = new Annotation(file); pipeline.annotate(document);